# Github does not delete a Rails model concern file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github

I have a Github Rails project, and I created a model concern. There were some bugs in it so I moved it out of the project folder and pushed the changes. However, now when I go to push changes the file magically appears right back into my repository as if I never deleted it... How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove it using the git rm command with the cached flag set.

```
git rm --cached /file/to/remove.rb
```